# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType'

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, for-loop

I have a function running that uploads the pandas dataframe to my database.

However, a lot of the values in the df are float values.

Originally the dataframe had incompatible datatypes but I changed them to their right datatypes except for the value that I want a float from.

There are some dates for which there is no value but mysql gives me this:

> 1947-01-01   =  1239 <-- supposed to be float and 1947-01-01  =
>   -9.22337e18 supposed to be null
>
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'NaTType'

```
for lines in countryDict[country_index]:

                      lines.splitlines()
                      fredder = fred.get_series_all_releases(lines)
                      pd.DataFrame(fredder)

                      fredder['date'] = fredder.date.astype('datetime64')
                      fredder['realtime_start'] = fredder.realtime_start.astype('datetime64')
                      fredder['value'] = fredder.value.astype('float64')

                      fredder.to_sql(
                                name = '{}'.format(lines),
                                con = engine,
                                index = False,
                                if_exists = 'append')



connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`pd.to_datetime(fredder['Date'])`

Comment: I dont have an issue with the date as much as I do for my values which are floats and some of then are null as well

Comment: You can add a condition and make it a zero if it's a null. This is if you don't have issues with putting zeros.